# CNN trained model doesn't appear to be working

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I've trained a CNN model and I would like to run the trained model against new data. However, it seems that the trained model isn't predicting the count correctly as it done during the training. I have a feeling that the model is not using the PTH file. Could someone please advise what I am doing wrong, please?

```
import argparse
import datetime
import glob
import os
import random
import shutil
import time
from os.path import join

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.optim as optim

from convnet3_eval import Convnet
from dataset2_eval import CellsDataset

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Predicting hits from pixels')
parser.add_argument('name',type=str,help='Name of experiment')
parser.add_argument('data_dir',type=str,help='Path to data directory containing images and gt.csv')
parser.add_argument('--weight_decay',type=float,default=0.0,help='Weight decay coefficient (something like 10^-5)')
parser.add_argument('--lr',type=float,default=0.0001,help='Learning rate')
args = parser.parse_args()

metadata = pd.read_csv(join(args.data_dir,'gt.csv'))
metadata.set_index('filename', inplace=True)


dataset = CellsDataset(args.data_dir,transform=ToTensor(),return_filenames=True)
dataset = DataLoader(dataset,num_workers=4,pin_memory=True)
model_path = '/base_model.pth'

model = Convnet()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=args.lr,weight_decay=args.weight_decay)

for images, paths in tqdm(dataset):

    targets = torch.tensor([metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]] for path in paths]) # B
    targets = targets.float()

    # code to print training data to a csv file
    filename=CellsDataset(args.data_dir,transform=ToTensor(),return_filenames=True)
    output = model(images) # B x 1 x 9 x 9 (analogous to a heatmap)
    preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3]) # predicted cell counts (vector of length B)
    print(preds)
    paths_test = np.array([paths])
    names_preds = np.hstack(paths)
    print(names_preds)                
    df=pd.DataFrame({'Image_Name':names_preds, 'Target':targets.detach(), 'Prediction':preds.detach()})
    print(df) 
    # save image name, targets, and predictions
    df.to_csv(r'model.csv', index=False, mode='a')


model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
model.eval()
```

Comment: Move the last two lines before the for-loop in which you make your predictions.

Comment: Many Thanks! Are you refering to those two lines: model = Convnet()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=args.lr,weight_decay=args.weight_decay) If i do this then i get an error message regarding this output = model(images).

Comment: Those two lines: `model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))` and `model.eval()`.

Comment: Just wrote an official answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the last two lines where you load the weights

```py
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_path))
model.eval()
```

above the for loop right below where you initialize the model.